# MATLAB: combine two cell arrays of string at a specific position

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have two cells of strings: A(a,1) and B(b,1), where a>b.
I want to combine A with B, adding B at a certain position of A.
Notice that in A there are no blank rows, so I suppose that first I have to add b blank rows in A and then concatenate B at a specific position.

Any suggestion?
Thank you :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want to place `B` in the position `p` of `A`. You can use indexing and concatenation of cell arrays like any other array types:

```
A = [A(1:p - 1, 1); B; A(p:end, 1)];
```